# How do I delete asyncstore when the application is closed

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

React Native - : How do I delete asyncstore when the application is closed.
Or What other method can I log in?
UseState in App.js is safe ?

Comment: why are you saving it to asyncStorage if you don't want it to persist?

Comment: What other method can I log in?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage is an unencrypted, asynchronous, `persistent`, key-value storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of LocalStorage.
If you don't wan't to persist the user data, probably you don't even need to use the AsyncStorage.

Normally AsyncStorage is used to store the user token and other info from the login information to keep the user logged in (unless they logout manually). If you don't want this behavior of a `persistent` storage, you can keep the usertoken in a local state of the application. This way, once you close the application, the local state will reset and the token will also get deleted, when the user access your application, they will have to login every time to use the app.

If this is something that you are looking for, you can look for maybe the react-context apis or redux reducers to store the login info. If you want to go with a persistent storage option, you can opt for `AsyncStorage`.

You can save data to AsyncStorage with

```js
AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
```

And delete the data with

```js
AsyncStorage.removeItem('@storage_Key', value)
```

You can read more about the `AsyncStorage` at https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage

Or you can choose [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) or [react-native-sensitive-info](https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info) which is more secure than using the `AsyncStorage` option.